# How to bundle ts types definitions with npm js library

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am trying to provide Typescript type definitions with a js library. Actually the library is written in Typescript and transpiled by Babel but ti shouldn't matter.

The problem is that type definitions are picked up by neither Intellij Idea nor by `ts-node`.

The library has the following config and files:

*package.json*

```
...
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
...
```

*build/index.js*

```
exports.Foo =  {
    bar: () => 'hello'
}
```

*build/index.d.ts*

```
export interface Foo {
    bar: () => string
}
```

Then in the ts code I get an error.

```
import { Foo } from 'apister'
Foo.bar()
// error TS2693: 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Why is not the type definitions recognized ?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are types, and do not exist at runtime.

It sounds like you want to declare either a class with a static method, or an object with a method.